# Installing Sitecore 9.3 Offline

Tags: solr, installation, sitecore-install-assistant

I am trying to install Sitecore 9.3 on one of our servers (not connected to the internet). **But in the end** it throws this error.

[image]

I installed Solr separately before installing Sitecore using traditional Keygen and NSSM methods since I was unable to Install Solr using SIA as it requires the internet to download files from the Apache server.

**How can I install Solr through SIA by configuring Solr-SingleDeveloper.json to pick downloaded files?**

**Or, even if I install Solr before, the service URL points to NSSM location instead of daemon directory (which is not created when installed manually)**

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is: you want to use an existing Solr Service (url), as you are installing Sitecore offline using SIA.

To achieve this do the following:

- First make sure the solr service you created is running and the solr instance is accessible through the url. The default url would be https://localhost:8983/solr.
- Now, from SIA, skip the "Install Solr" step. Screenshot below for reference:

[image: Skip Install Solr]

- Then in "Solr Settings" (6th step in SIA), just add the Solr url, Solr File System Root path and Solr Service name which you want to use and have already installed and you should be good to go.

[image]

Once the Sitecore installation is complete you can quickly verify the Solr instance being used by your instance from the ConnectionStrings.config.

Comment: Thanks. I did all these things. Installed Solr separately. This is where I am getting this error (screenshot in question). It is unable to find Solr service in the last step. Because of this, it is just installing plain Sitecore and not SXA.